# Do I need to call new for autoproperties?

Tags: c#, properties

If i have an autoproperty  :

```
public List<IObjects> MyObjects {get; set;}
```

Do i need to call `MyObjects = new List<IObjects>();` in constructor ?

Comment: If you want it to be initialized, yes.

Comment: What happens when you try to add to the list without initializing it?

Comment: @Wheels73 Backing fields would be null, i expect an NullReferenceException

Comment: @YthioCsi - That's correct. You have your answer! :)

Comment: @Wheels73: Except you don't have to do it in the constructor, you can just as easily do it in a method or since it is public set it via the property from a different class... I don't know if the "in constructor" was the important bit or "do I need to call" but its always good to be precise. :)

Comment: @Chris - Yeah good shout Chris... i thought it was more to do with the fact it was an auto property and given that it wires up a holding var underneath, does initialize it for you.

Comment: *In general*, settable `List<T>` properties don't work out well. They allow external code to *replace the collection entirely*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever In C#5, you have to put a setter in your properties, unless you mark it abstract or extern (from the error i get if I remove the setter). You can have a private setter though.

Answer (score 1):

Autoproperties will have their default value if you don't set it to anything else. That is the equivalent of `MyObjects = default(List<IObjects>)`. In this case that would be null. I make the point of talking about how it is `default(T)` because in the case of something like int it will be `default(int)` (ie 0) so it is important to think of it as being the default and not null.

It is worth noting that you don't have to do this in the constructor - it is not readonly. You could quite happily set it to a value elsewhere (eg `MyClass.MyObjects = myList`) or indeed leave it unset entirely if you wanted to (and it made sense to do so).

Answer (score -1):

It is not necessary to initialize the auto implemented property in the constructor. It has the default value and it is null.